# Yum with crontab - "Another app is currently holding the yum lock"

Tags: cron, yum

I want to use crontab to run a script for yum updates. The problem is it seems it will run the script once, then yum is just stuck for a while (and can't be ran again). I get this error:

```
$ sudo yum update
Existing lock /var/run/yum.pid: another copy is running as pid 5248.
Another app is currently holding the yum lock; waiting for it to exit...
The other application is: yum
Memory:...
Started:... 5 day(s) ago...
State: Sleeping, pid: 5248
```

This is what I place in crontab:

```
$ sudo crontab -e
0 4 * * *
/usr/local/bin/yum_updates.sh
```

This is what's in the script:

```
$ sudo vim /usr/local/bin/yum_updates.sh
#!/bin/bash
yum makecache
yum -y update
yum -y upgrade
mandb
```

I considered yum-cron, but I've looked over the config file and it doesn't seem as customizable as crontab (i.e. I can't run security updates one day and full updates a different day), but correct me if I'm wrong, I haven't used yum-cron that much.

I would like to know how to stop this error, so I can run scripts using crontab without it holding the program hostage or getting the process stuck after only running once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great answers, but I found I could just make each type of yum update its own crontab entry like so:

```
$ sudo crontab -e

#Full system update midnight every Monday and Tuesday
0 0 * * 1,2 /usr/bin/yum -y update

10 0 * * 1,2 /usr/bin/yum -y upgrade

#Security updates everyday at 2AM
0 2 * * * /usr/bin/yum -y update --security
```

Takes more lines, but seems to work just fine. It needs to be noted that each entry should have a blank line below it, especially the last entry.

Answer (score 0):

change your script to

```
#!/bin/bash
#this line will kill that process is runing yum 
kill -9 `ps -aux | grep yum |tr -s " " : | cut -f2 -d : | head -1` 
yum makecache
kill -9 `ps -aux | grep yum |tr -s " " : | cut -f2 -d : | head -1`
yum -y update
yum -y upgrade
mandb
```

Comment: _Much_ safer to just use `pkill yum` instead of that pipeline...  If there are lock files, your code would not remove them (I'm not a `yum` user).  Also, `kill -9` is almost always overkill.

Comment: `pkill yum` will not working. you can try @Kusalananda

Comment: Well, `pkill -f yum` would match `yum` anywhere on the command line.

Comment: `pkill -f yum ` will not kill yum . i tried it now @Kusalananda

Answer (score 0):

Killing yum ins't what you want, I mean you will get package corruption at some time for sure.
There is package like yum-cron that can solve your problem in proper manner.
Install it, edit /etc/yum/yum-cron.conf according to your needs (install security only or all)

enable service and start it.

You will not longer need to worry about half done updates/upgrades or any other problems that killing might result in

Answer (score 0):

#### yum-cron

There's no need to do your own crontab entry to run YUM periodically. YUM has a addon package called `yum-cron`. This tutorial, titled: [How to enable automatic security updates on CentOS 7 with yum-cron](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-enable-automatic-security-updates-on-centos-7-with-yum-cron/), shows how to configure and operate it.

First make sure it's installed:

```
$ sudo yum -y install yum-cron
```

Then configure it:

```
$ cat /etc/yum/yum-cron.conf
....
apply_updates = yes
```

Enable & start the service:
Once you've made the necessary changes, be sure that the service is enabled and running/restarted:

```
$ sudo systemctl enable --now yum-cron
```

#### What else?

Keep in mind that doing all your updates is just the tip of what `yum-cron` can do. You can also configure it to exclude specific packages that you'd prefer it not deal with:

```
exclude = kernel*
```

#### References

- [yum-cron man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/yum-cron.8.html)
- [How to enable automatic security updates on CentOS 7 with yum-cron](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-enable-automatic-security-updates-on-centos-7-with-yum-cron/)

Comment: Yes, but yum-cron is not as customizable with the times, correct? I would like to run certain updates certain times of the month/week/day and certain updates at other times. Do you know why yum gets locked up with crontab? Is that a yum problem or do other programs that are ran in a script (automated with crontab) get stuck too?

Comment: So run yum-cron but not in daemon mode. You can run it as an interactive program from Cron, just guard calling it by making sure it isn't already running.